# Additional column in cross tab crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I need to add additional columns and rows in cross tab crystal report. 
I have posted my detail info [here in sap](https://answers.sap.com/questions/387679/add-additional-columns-in-cross-tab-report.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go to preview and the if rows right click on last row and if on columns right click on last column and then insert row or column.